# Is there a way to partition the hard drive in which the OS is installed?

Tags: linux, partition, dual-boot

This is what I get by doing `parted -l`:

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA TOSHIBA DT01ACA1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
1       1049kB  512MB   511MB   primary   ext4         boot
2       513MB   1000GB  1000GB  extended
5       513MB   1000GB  1000GB  logical   btrfs
```

I want to partition my hard drive for dual-booting.The hard drive I am now using has a GNU/Linux distro installed (Parrot OS). Is there a way that I can partition the hard disk (I think `/dev/sda`) without losing its data? Such that I can install MS Windows in the new partition?

Comment: I see two problems -  No unallocated space on your disk for another partition unless you shrink the btrfs partition, and Windows expects a GPT-partitioned disk - not an MBR-partitioned disk.

Comment: If newer system that is UEFI, then you should be booting systems in UEFI. Microsoft requires gpt for UEFI boot and requires MBR for BIOS boot. How you boot install media, is then how it installs. Have good backups before any changes. If Windows converts drive to gpt as part of a UEFI/gpt install it will erase entire drive. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode since 2012.  Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html

Comment: Thank you all for the help,but i went the other way.i backed up my system ,and partitioned at the time of new installation.and i did some informative reading about partitioning.(And i dont know how to close the question)

Answer (score 0):

Use `gparted` it is a live distro containing `gparted`. It can do the re-size and add partitions. I don't know about changing the partition table type though. It seems possible, but I have never done it.

Answer (score 0):

`parted` messes up with sizes using the newer 1GB=1000MB while Linux actually uses 1GiB=1024MiB. So you have to use old fashioned fdisk and all the other compatible Linux built-in commands to do the trick.

You need to learn:

```
lsblk –f #check current partition names
fdisk -l #check partition physical profiles
e2fsck –f [partition name] #a detailed look at partition profile
resize2fs –f [partition device] [desired volumn] #shrink partition size
fdisk #set up a new partition on the unallocated space just spared
```